# What's the best way to bulk update Jenkins projects?

Tags: jenkins

We have hundreds of Jenkins projects (mostly created from a few templates), often need to make the same change to all of them. e.g. today I need to add a post-build step to delete workspace at the end. Next I need to change the step to copy build result to a shared drive to Nexus repository.

What's the best way to apply such kind of bulk change to Jenkins projects?

Comment: I'm not sure if this has enough options for you but I've used the Jobcopy Builder plugin in the past to do something similar, you can use this to copy jobs and specify strings to find and replace in the config

Comment: If it's auto generated jobs configurations, you can go to $Jenkins_Home/jobs on your master and string-replace-add what you need. I used it to change all jdk configurations for all jobs starting with Master-*, it's quite easy to do in a shell script.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) which is designed to do this.

It supports many configuration options.

Answer (score 9):

Groovy is by far the best way to bulk update jobs. You may have to do a little digging into the jenkins / plugin api to figure out what api calls to make, but the script console (http://yourJenkinsUrl/script) provides an easy way to play around with the code until you get it right.

To get you started, you can add / remove post-build steps by calling the `getPublishersList()` method on a job and then calling the add / remove methods.

```
def publishersList = Jenkins.instance.getJob("JobName").getPublishersList()
publishersList.removeAll { it.class == whatever.plugin.class }
publishersList.add(new PluginConstructor())
```

If you're not sure what publisher class you need to delete the workspace, I would suggest manually adding the desired configurations to one job, and then run `getPublishersList()` from the script console on that job. You will see the class you are working with in the list, and then you can go look at the api to see what is required to construct it.

You can then iterate through all your jobs and add the publisher doing something like this:

```
Jenkins.instance.getView("All Jobs").items.each { job ->
    //Maybe some logic here to filter out specific jobs

    job.getPublishersList().add(new PluginConstructor())
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Jenkins CLI api or the REST api, but in order to update post-build actions, you will have to modify the project configuration xml file (which isn't trivial programmatically configure) and then overwrite the job configuration with the new configuration file.

Comment: I use `Jenkins.instance.items` to get the list of all jobs. `Jenkins.instance.getView("All Jobs")` doesn't work for me, perhaps because it depends on a specific view. Also, the [Jenkins Script Console wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) is a good place to find example scripts.

Comment: Sorry. Oversight on my part. I edited my answer with the correct code.

Answer (score 9):

The [REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) is quite powerful. The following sequence worked for me:

In loop for all relevant projects (list of projects is available via e.g. `/api/xml?tree=jobs[name]`):

- download `config.xml` via `/job/{name}/config.xml`
- edit using your favorite scripted xml editor (mine was [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/))
- upload new `config xml` via `/job/{name}/config.xml`

Some random notes:

- do *BACKUP* before doing anything
- I probably could post some bash script example if anyone is interested

Good luck!

EDIT> Example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

jenkinsUrlBase='http://user:token@jenkins'

callJenkins() { # funcPath
    curl --silent --show-error -g "${jenkinsUrlBase}${1}"
}

postJenkinsFile() { # funcPath fileName
    curl --silent --show-error -g -d "@${2}" "${jenkinsUrlBase}${1}"
}

callJenkins '/api/xml?tree=jobs[name]' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//hudson/job/name' | while read projectName ; do

    echo "Processing ${projectName}..."
    origFile="${projectName}_old.xml"
    newFile="${projectName}_new.xml"
    callJenkins "/job/${projectName}/config.xml" > "$origFile"

    echo " - Updating artifactory url..."
    cat "$origFile" \
        | xmlstarlet ed -P -u '//maven2-moduleset/publishers/org.jfrog.hudson.ArtifactoryRedeployPublisher/details/artifactoryUrl' -v "http://newServer/artifactory" \
    > "${newFile}"

    if false ; then
        echo " - Commiting new config file..."
        postJenkinsFile "/job/${projectName}/config.xml" "$newFile"
    else
        echo " - Dry run: not commiting new config file"
    fi

done
```

Comment: Don't you need to reload Jenkins for the filesystem changes to take effect?

Comment: @Slav As far as I know changes via REST API behave the same as changes via web interface -- thus no reload should be needed. (IMHO) You would need to reload Jenkins if you changed the config files directly in the filesystem but the method in the answer works differently.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the `config.xml` file with your favorite text tool (I use Python) and then reload the jenkins configuration.

In my setup the jobs are stored in `~/.jenkins/jobs/*/config.xml`.

See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Here is a small example to update `foo` to `bar`:

```
    </com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>additional_requirements</name>
          <description>foo</description>
...
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, unicode_literals, print_function

import sys
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict


def change_parameter_description(config_xml_path, parameter_name, new_description):
    tree=etree.parse(config_xml_path)

    for tag in tree.findall('.//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition'):
        name_tag=tag.find('./name')
        if not name_tag.text==parameter_name:
            continue
        description=tag.find('./description')
        description.text=new_description
    tree.write(config_xml_path)


for config_xml_path in sys.argv[1:]:
    change_parameter_description(config_xml_path, 'additional_requirements', 'bar')
```

In this small example a regex would work, but if things span several lines, it is better to work with xml tools :-)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great, but if you use pipelines, I'd suggest you to use [Pipeline Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

We have all our jobs in a git repository. To develop a new feature we try it in a branch, since it is possible to point just one job to a specific branch. When we need to update them, just merge into master. The jobs are treated as code, with a proper release process.

Comment: This response seems incomplete.  Yes, you can keep your pipeline scripts as code, but you still need a job defined within Jenkins that invokes the pipeline.  Or are you saying you have EVERYTHING related to Jenkins jobs in your source control?  If so, how does Jenkins visualize that and run your jobs?

Comment: @RussJackson the idea is that the individuals jobs are very lightweight. They just refer to the code repository and the shared lib. All the job logic must be in the shared lib.