# Updating user emails in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins setup in which jobs are pipelines that call the `email-ext` plugin to notify users.

After the jobs have been setup, all users have changed emails, going from `user@company1.com` to `user@company2.com`.

Jenkins still sends emails to the former adresses.
I can't find a way to update the email adresses. Is there a way to do this ?
Users are authenticated through the Active Directory plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to update **to** address while sending. Check [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-PipelineExamples) on how to do it. Since you might need to update the config on multiple jobs you might need to write a script to achieve that. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441636/whats-the-best-way-to-bulk-update-jenkins-projects) explains it